# Rotating cirle anime js

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I'm trying to let a cricle spin and on mouseenter I want the circle to stop spinning and rotate "x" degree, on mouseleave the circle should spin back to its origin and continue the spinning animation.

```
function rotatingCircle(degree) {
    var test = 
    anime({
    targets: [document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]],
    rotate: degree,
    duration: 800,
    loop: true,
    elasticity: 0,
    easing: "linear"

  });
};

rotatingCircle(360);

var buttonEl = document.querySelector('.trigger');
var circleOne = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");


buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', rotatingCircle(20));

buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', rotatingCircle(0));
```

Add the moment my svg is not rotating at all. When I remove the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' event, then my svg is rotating as wanted. How do I keep a rotating loop animation AND can add a 'mouseenter' / 'mouseleave' event, which triggers the rotating SVG to rotate to a specifig angle?

Comment: Could you rephrase that into a question and explain where you are stuck?

Comment: Add the moment my svg is not rotating at all. When I remove the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' event, then my svg is rotating as wanted. 

How do I keep a rotating loop animation AND can add a 'mouseenter' / 'mouseleave' event, which triggers the rotating SVG to rotate to a specifig angle?

Answer (score 1):

### One problem I see with your code is that

```
buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', rotatingCircle(20));
buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', rotatingCircle(0));
```

are actually calling the function `rotatingCircle` where as you want to send a function name or anonymous function here instead.

### Function name example if these were parameterless functions

```
buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', rotatingCircle);
buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', rotatingCircle);
```

### Anonymous function example when you need to send parameters **(use this one)**

```
buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => rotatingCircle(20));
buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => rotatingCircle(20));
```

### How to think about it with an example:

listeners just need the reference to what to call when they are triggered, they don't need what the function returns from calling

I made a code sandbox of what I think you are talking about. Check it out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/aninejs-different-animations-for-different-hover-states-ld76r